# How do I set placeholder if the image is null?

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso, let

I get an image from the server and use `Picasso` to set it in ImageView. The image can be null so I use `let`. But when the image is null I get an error. How can I use let to set placeholder if the image is null?
My function:

```
contactsModel.images?.let { url ->
       Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(url)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_placeholder)
       .into(mContactIcon) }
```

My error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:297)
```

Comment: `setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_person_placeholder)`?

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder is used for holding image for the network image. If you want to use the placeholder image when there is a error loading image in the view then kindly use it with `error` call.

```
.error(R.drawable.ic_person_placeholder)
```

as shown in the answer https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-placeholders-errors-and-fading

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways but you can simply check if the URL is empty. then use an image from drawable and add to your image view. use something like this -

```
if (url.isEmpty()) {
   iview.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
} else{
    Picasso.get().load(url).into(iview);
  }
```

Comment: I know the solution with the if statement. I need to do with let or run

Comment: these images are coming from the server. then check there and if images are null add a default placeholder image URL to that key